# Can I navigate Image Uploader with cURL?

Tags: php, curl, image-uploading, aurigma

I'm wondering if anyone knows if manipulating the Aurigma Image Uploader using cURL is possible. Basically what I need to do is transfer images that are uploaded to my site (not using aurigma), and using web scripting (I'd assume cURL) send those photos to another site that is password protected but that uses Aurigma Image Uploader to receive photos. So I would need to be able to navigate to the correct upload folder on my desktop, then select all the photos in that folder and then upload them. I can't connect to the server directly using POST, so that option is out of the question. So any advice on how to accomplish this would be great. Thanks.

**EDIT**

To explain the process that needs to happen. Site/Server 1 receives images that are uploaded to it from users using a generic image uploading script. Site/Server 2 receives images that are uploaded to it via the Aurigma Image uploader. My question is whether a script can be created to transfer directly the images received on Server 1 to server 2? The script would see the uploaded images on server 1 and then navigate through the password protection on server 2, navigate to the area of the site to upload, then use the site's installation of Aurigma Image uploader to choose the images that were uploaded to server 1, select them, then upload them to server 2 using the aurigma image uploader.

I cannot access the server directly through POST methods, that is why I need to basically walk through the site using a created script, then have the script control which pictures to upload to server 2 based on what was uploaded to server 1. Clear as mud? :)

Comment: Please clarify you question. Do you need to transfer photos from one web site to another? Or do you want Image Uploader to upload photos from client side NOT using POST?

Comment: @Eugene Please see the edit in the original question. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to upload photos from **server 1** (where you upload images using ‘web scripting’) to **server 2** (‘another site that is password protected’) using Aurigma Image Uploader. Image Uploader does not support adding files to upload list from Java Script, this way, you cannot select files and initiate upload from your code.

Image Uploader sends files using HTTP POST requests, so you can try to form your own request compatible with Image Uploader API: [POST Field Reference](http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu7/post-field-reference.htm).

Comment: +1 for the API reference. I couldn't seem to find that in my searches. Please see the edit to the original question for more clarification. Though it sounds like from your response, that manipulating and navigating aurigma with a script is not possible. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: I would rephrase it - Image Uploader JavaScript API does not contain methods to add files to upload list due to security reasons. However it contains bunch of JavaScript methods and events for seamless integration with Web projects.

Comment: I know this is old, but were you ever able to form a proper curl request for image upload?